# Redirect all subdomains to file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, web

I have a server to which many domains points. So I need a generic .htaccess rule. I need to create a .htaccess file which redirects all subdomains to their correspondent subdomain folder.
Is that possible? Thanks.

For example:

`http(s)://apple.domain1.com -> https://domain1.com/redir/apple/index..html`

`http(s)://orange.2domain.co.uk -> https://2domain.co.uk/redir/orange/index.asp`

`http(s)://banana.doma3n.org -> https://doma3n.org/redir/banana/index.php`

Comment: There are a few challenges here, nothing difficult, except for one detail for which I don't see any immediate solution: how should your redirection logic know whether the desired target is a html page, a php script or an asp whatever? THat cannot be derived from the incoming request. Can _you_ tell?

Comment: Inside each "redir" folder will be only one file with the subdomain name. For example, when using apple.domain1.com the htaccess should look for anything with "apple" inside "redir" folder. But well, if that's not possible, I can standardize everything to be a .php script, if it's easier or doable

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at how the http server's `DirectoryIndex` directive works which is provided by "mod_dir":  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html That allows to detect existing files but I fail to see how that should work if the index file is named different for each host. That is a _very_ strange setup. I suggest you rename all those files to "index.XXX" where "XXX" is whatever file name ending. That is how the `DirectoryIndex` directive can easily handle the task.

Comment: And I'd have a subfolder for each domain? Like apple would have domain.com/apple/index.html ?

Comment: No, that is not requrired. It is easy to evaluate the requested host and act accordingly. You simple internally rewrite to a folder named as the name of the "subdomain". And in there you have _some_ index file. Can be index.html, index.php, index.asp, index.brainfuck, does not matter, as long as those names are registered as valid index documents.

Comment: If that is fine with you and you are willing to name your documents such, then modify your question accordingly and I can post an answer.

Comment: Done! Note that I also need to force https even if the request came from http.

Comment: Also is it possible to either verify if the request is made from an internal IP such as 10.0.0.1 and if yes, redirect the whole thing to the subfolder redir_internal instead of redir?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so now it suddenly are three questions in one :-)

I don't really understand why you need separate folders for this. Why not *one* script that handles those requests, regardless on what host ("subdomain") is called? The script knows about what host has been called, so it can act accordingly.

Anyway, your question is how to rewrite to separate folders, so that is what I will answer to...

In addition to rewriting hosts acting as landing pages you also want to configure your default host (the fallback host) such that it delivers something that does make sense.

Anyway, this should point you into the right direction:

---

First you need to configure your `DirectoryIndex`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectoryIndex index.asp
```

Consult the documentation for more details and where to place those directives: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

---

Second you need to rewrite the incoming requests to internal directories:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.
RewriteRule ^ /redir_internal [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteCond -d %1
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [END]

RewriteRule ^ /something_that_acts_as_a_fallback
```

Consult the documentation for more details: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).